# Setting Alignment of \s1\ on the document - DocuSign for salesforce

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending documents for signature from  salesforce using DocuSign. I am having an issue with aligning the tag - \s1\, \t1\, \d1\ on the document.

My understanding is Docusign will replace tags automatically for specific signers to sign. But they are off by few pixels and come over the line marked in the document.

could anyone tell me how i could configure sure that the user don't enter details over the line on the document but above the line.

Thanks in advance for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting proper tag placement with anchor text usually takes some trial and error -- i.e., testing DocuSign tag placement based upon various positions of the anchor text strings (\s1\,\t1\, \d1\, etc.) that you put in your document(s).

One tip:  If you're creating your documents (i.e., adding the anchor text strings) with Word or something similar, putting each anchor text string inside a textbox (with no textbox borders) is a good way to give you more finite control over tag placement -- because you can move the textbox wherever you want to, regardless of where underlying text exists in the document. For example, here's a screenshot from Word where I've added an **\s1** tag inside a textbox, and placed it precisely where I want it over the signature line:

[image: DS anchor string]

If I sent this document through DocuSign and thought the Signature tag was placed lower than I wanted it to be, I'd just edit the document to move the textbox up a few pixels (without affecting the signature line placement itself), and then re-test.